# Adobe Air custom statusbar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, adobe, statusbar

I've been looking for some examples on creating a custom statusbar for an AIR application, but haven't found anything really useful.  That was until I started looking around in the Tour de Flex AIR app for an example, and it was right there (part of the app itself). Would anyone have some suggestions on replicating this statusbar.  The trouble I'm having is that I cannot seem to get the value of a dynamic variable to display. I'm attempting to display the current user.

Answer (score 2):

In your application's `initialize` handler:

```
statusBarFactory = new ClassFactory(yourpackage.yourStatusBarClassName);
```

Application will create status bar from your class.

Answer (score 0):

In your descriptor xml, make the `systemChrome` tag false, then it's just a matter of imagining how you want to make your status bar look and implement it.